# Hypothetical future space scenario question?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, evolution, terraforming

Could human scientists use terraformed or Paraterraformed worlds in our solar system like our moon or mars to run unimaginable large scale Experimental Evolution Projects to see how life might evolve isolated on other words with organisms that have rapid generations and breed fast?

What issues (besides ethical or financial ones) might arise in the process of doing this?

What might the potential benefits or risk be from running a experimental evolution project on such a large scale ?

Comment: Problem: evolution takes an *extremely* long time. Whoever starts this experiment would be *long* dead by the time anything significant evolves on another planet.

Comment: Also, please consider changing the title of your question to be more specific. Thanks!

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer He does not technically specify that the scientists need be human or mortal...

Comment: @Nosajimiki Good point. I wish the OP would elaborate on details like this in the question...

Comment: Scientists *could* do lots of things, but that doesn't mean doing those things are worthwhile. It only means that there is apparently a staggeringly large grant available.

Comment: @user535733 Opps that grant was supposed to be for 10 billion ¥, not 10 billion ₿

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only a species that lives MUCH longer than another can witness its evolution.  For example, some microbial organisms reproduce as quickly as once every 20 minutes.  In this case, humans can observe thousands of generations of the microbe in a single human life time and collect enough data to make observations about its evolution.

The thing about microbial life though is that you don't need a whole world to see how things will play out, a simple lab setting can be used to create environmental factors just like any alien world you would want to examine microbial life on rendering the need for terraformed worlds rather excessive.

If you want to study the evolution of macroscopic organisms though, that is where you need a much bigger lab and life expectancy.  If your scientists are aliens/AIs/gods/etc who live for millions of years and who want to study the evolution of a longer lived creature like humans, then using terraformed worlds would seem fairly reasonable.  Terraforming a world only takes a few thousand years; so, if you're going to live that long a thousand times over anyway, it does not seem like a supper big investment of time; so, such an expenditure would seem no different than a human scientist spending a few weeks getting a lab setup for a major experiment. Then once you transplant your specimens in thier different habitats, you just go off for a few thousand years at a time to work on other things coming back every once in a while to log the progress of your experiment.

Comment: @Ciaran Eldrett Welcome to worldbuilding.stackexchange.com, worldbuilding is a bit different than some of the other stackexchange sites in that answers on here are often a bit more subjective in nature.  Just because I was able to answer your question does not mean that mine will be the best answer out there; so, it's normally best to wait at least 24hr before accepting an answer to see if anyone else might have better insights.  It's not really a problem to accept an answer right away, but it does tend to get you better results to wait a bit.

Answer (score 1):

First your habitat size needs to be considered, on mars for example (could be any inhospitable world) you would get your lab set up more quickly in a closed structure (Domes, sealed caves, etc.) Because then terraforming the planet is unnecessary.

So, the size of the habitat needs to fit with your species natural range. Do they migrate, fly, swim, tunnel, use tools? All of these things have to be considered. Your walls need to keep them inside and safe from the outside environment.

They will also need enough room to grow their population as the generations come along. You may have to expand during the experiment or have the world terraformed while they are in their closed habitat so they can expand later.

It is crucial to have a species with generations much much shorter than the scientist's lifespan or the whole thing will be abandoned after they die(another story I think).

Comment: The only potential problem here is that the dome becomes an extraneous variable which could be seen as corrupting the results.  An animal in a dome may work out fine in the dome and adapt very well to the dome, but open worlds have many different climates that change over time.  An animal that is permitted to occasionally migrate too far north and face -10C weather will evolve to be more adaptable than one raised in a climate controlled dome with a fixed cycle of 0-20C, or if you set enough randomness in your dome that it kills 95% of your population by dropping to -10C, you get a bottleneck.

Comment: Whereas a world might experience -10C in one place selecting for a cold resistant gene while still leaving enough of them alone down at the equator where it's 20C that you don't risk wiping everyone out. So, if you use domes, you'll need to account for how to simulate climate ranges and cross region traffic.